# where Xcode organizer stores devices list

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can any body tell me where xcode organizer saves the list of devices attached with it???

I need that urgently. I am unable to add device from provisioning portal and need to add device from xcode organizer but that needs the device. i currently don't have the device just have the UDID.
I think i could add the device UDID in the xcode organizer list then i can add the device from the xcode organier to the program portal.

Regards
Abdul Samad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.xcode.plist
```

Look for the `XCKnownRemoteComputers` key.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your reply. Do all of these values are mandatory or we have to give only udid???

regards
Abdul samad